# How to change Monolog channel for some controllers Symfony 3.4 or 4+

Tags: symfony, autowired, monolog, symfony4

I want to change Monolog channel. My declarations works with some classes but never with controllers.

Here is my new *admin* channel declaration:

```
#config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        admin:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%-admin.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["admin"]
```

I use it successfuly with my Authenticator by adding a tag:

```
#config/services.yaml
# The form guard authenticator for the admin access
app.security.admin_authenticator:
    class: App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
    autowire: true
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: admin}
```

The last line of `services.yaml` file do the job, my Authenticator is no more logging in *app* channel, it's logging in *admin* channel.

Now, I want to use this channel with the controllers under the Admin subdirectory, so I add a similar tag in my declaration:

```
#config/services.yaml
App\Controller\Admin\:
    resource: '../src/Controller/Admin'
    tags:
        - 'controller.service_arguments'
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: admin}
```

But it seems there is no impact. I am still logging in *app* channel.
(I did some verification, like refresh the cache). I don't find my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it most probably because your controller doesn't implement `LoggerAwareInterface` thus the logger tag has no impact.

Check which interface `AdminAuthenticator` is implementing (to see how the logger is being set) then do the same for the controller it should work.

```
#services.yaml
App\Controller\Admin\:
    resource: '../src/Controller/Admin'
    calls:
        - [ setLogger, [ '@logger' ] ]
    tags:
        - 'controller.service_arguments'
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: admin}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I will test it tommorow morning!

Comment: Even if I implement LoggerAwareInterface, the logger tag has no impact. So I will use the solution of @MatMouth . But I won't use the constructor. I will call the setLogger and implement the LoggerAwareInterface with a declaration in services.yaml

Comment: The tag will be read by the logger anyway, with implementing `LoggerAwareInterface`you may have to do the wiring manually though, eg : adding `- [ setLogger, [ '@logger' ] ]` under `calls:` just before `tags`

Answer (score 5):

I cannot figure it out with the tag method. However, you can define your monolog channel as argument of your controller constructor:

```
# monolog package configuration
monolog:
    channels: [ 'admin' ]
    handlers:
        admin:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%-admin.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["admin"]
```

Auto-wiring configuration:

```
#config/services.yaml
App\Controller\Admin\:
    resource: '../src/Controller/Admin'
    arguments:
        $logger: '@monolog.logger.admin'
    tags:
        - 'controller.service_arguments'
```

And in your controllers

```
/**
 * SecurityController constructor.
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I will test it tommorow morning!

Comment: Yes it works. But, I think it is not the best practice to add a constructor on a controller. So, I implement LoggerAwareInterface and call the setLogger method in services.yaml .The solution suggested by mrbm works with tag.